# Change event on <select>

Tags: javascript, html-select, mootools, mootools-events

With Mootools, if I attach a change event listener on a `<select>` how do I access the option that was selected.  I would like the actual element and not just the value.

```
$('select').addEvent('change',function(event) {
    //??
});
```

Comment: e.target maybe? just guessing here though

Comment: event.target only points to the <select> element

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either of these will work:

find by :selected pseudo selector in descendants

```
this.getElement(':selected');
```

get first selected value

```
this.getSelected()[0];
```

pure javascript, use the selectedIndex property

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 4):

Just access the `selectedIndex` property on the select element (`this` object in the event handler) to get the option index.

```
// get the index of the selected option
var index = this.selectedIndex;

// get the option element
var opt   = this.options[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.id` is the object

`event.target.value` is the new value