# <option> Events in Mobile Safari <select> list>

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm just trying to get selecting a menu item from a `<select>` list to be a 2 tap interaction vs. a 3 tap interaction.

Comment: I've tried placing the events one might expect (onBlur, onChange, onClick, onFocus, onChange, onSelect, onMouseOver, onMove, onTouch) in the <option> tags, which didn't work.I've also done a fair amount of Googling for a solution and haven't turned up anything.

Answer (score 0):

As the `option`'s are just values to the `select`, you will normally [register events to the select-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460875/change-event-on-select) instead of the option-element. I'm not sure if this is even allowed via the DOM-spec, but I also can't find any reliable sources right now.

Comment: I know. The high-level issue is that Mobile Safari's implementation of the select element creates moments where one might expect events, but unfortunately events aren't generated by the DOM.